# Shell prompt: \W shown as '\w', left puzzled

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, bashrc

TL;DR:

PS1 is not as it's supposed to be.
`PS1="\W"` shows as `\w█` the block being the blinking cursor. The folder name will appear only after directory change. OS is Debian 9.9 Stretch. I'm not quite sure where I've made a mistake and kindly ask for others to take a look and give their educated opinions.

Below is my `.bashrc`:

```bsh
RED='\[\033[31m\]'
BOLD_RED='\[\033[1;31m\]'
YELLOW='\[\033[33m\]'
GREEN='\[\033[32m\]'
BLUE='\[\033[01;34m\]'
BOLD_BLUISH='\[\033[01;32m\]'
NORMAL='\[\033[00m\]'

USR='\u'
TIME='\t'
PWD='\w'
DIR='\W'
RIGHTS='\$'
RESET='\[$(tput sgr0)\]'

if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    PS1="$NORMAL\t·$BOLD_RED\u@\h$NORMAL·$GREEN$DIR·$NORMAL\$ $RESET"
else
    PS1="$GREEN\t$NORMAL·$BOLD_BLUISH\u@\h$NORMAL·$BLUE$DIR$NORMAL·\$ $RESET"
fi
```

Comment: You set `PWD` to '`\w`', but `PWD` is supposed to be the current working directory (the shell sets it every time you change directories). This is why you should use lower- or mixed-case variable names for your stuff; there are a lot of all-caps names with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of them for something else, it can cause weird problems. Like this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious! I'm surprised how I failed to notice it myself.

Comment: what is the difference between `\w` vs `\W`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `PWD` is a shell variable. From `man 1 bash`:

> `PWD` The current working directory as set by the `cd` command.

Bash updates this variable whenever the current working directory changes. It appears that if `PS1` uses `\W` or `\w`, the prompt reads from the variable, so if you do (or just did) `PWD='\w'` then the prompt will show literal `\w`. Try it with another value (e.g. `PWD="Oh boy, this string should not appear in my prompt!"`) and your prompt will reflect this.

After `cd` the shell updates the variable and the prompt behaves like `PS1="\W"` should.

General solution: [use `lowercase` names for your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

Comment: Thank you!

Apparently I did make not one, but even two mistakes!
First being, the one you pointed out, using commands as variables (`dir` & `pwd`) and the second forgetting and mixing up that variables should be lower-, not uppercase.

Comment: what is the difference between `\w` vs `\W`?

Comment: @CharlieParker Read about `\w` and `\W` here: [Bash Reference Manual, Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt).